# How to access mysql that which is in docker container from another host machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a docker instance which also includes mysql in this image, now i want to check whether my mysql is accessible remotely or not ?

How to check whether the connection is established or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [issue 95](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/95): make sure you map the port used by your mysql image to a port of your host (if Linux)

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
```

[image: http://severalnines.com/sites/default/files/blog/node_4734/image04.png]

And if you use docker with VirtualBox (Windows or Mac), you would need to port-forward that port to your actual host

```
VBoxManage controlvm "default" natpf1 "tcp-port3306,tcp,,3306,,3306";
```

And use docker-machine ip default to get the actual address.

You would not need that if you are using docker for Windows (HyperV) or [for Mac (HyperKit)](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/).

See "[MySQL Docker Containers: Understanding the basics](https://severalnines.com/blog/mysql-docker-containers-understanding-basics)" for more.

---

Update March 2017, from the same [issue 95](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/95)

[aercolino](https://github.com/aercolino) reports in [this comment](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/95#issuecomment-294179119):

> I just found out I can connect SequelPro to a MySQL server on Docker with these data: (no need for the IP of the server)

```
Host: 0.0.0.0
Port: 32768
Username: wordpress
Password: wordpress
```

> I posted my configuration here: [How to install WordPress with Docker on OS Sierra](http://andowebsit.es/blog/noteslog.com/post/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-on-os-sierra/)

That could work, but `0.0.0.0` is the [broadcast address of the zero network or `0.0.0.0`, which in Internet Protocol standards stands for this network, i.e. the local network.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address). Not always safe to use.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, I will try checking with your solution. Will get back if there is any problem.